# Resize ExpandableListView's background on expand and collapse

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview, nine-patch, responsiveness

I have an `expandableListView` with a 9.patch background, which looks like the image below while all of its headers are collapsed:

[image: Collapsed list]

By default, when a header is expanded, the whole view is converted to a scroll view, like this:

[image]

But what I want is to resize the background when a header is expanded, so all other headers and items are visible without scrolling:

[image]

And of-course resized back to the smaller view (first picture) when the header is collpased again.

How should I achive this?

Comment: What you want is not using `ExpandableListView`. You need a simple layout, which will expand/collapse. If you don't need animation, you can just make `setVisibility(VISIBLE)` to the *child view* on click of the *group view*

Comment: @VladMatvienko How am I supposed to do this while I have a dynamic list of headers and each of them has a dynamic list of childs/items ?

Comment: dynamically add views? `viewGroup.add(View)` Why not?

Answer (score 0):

I put into practice what @Vladyslav Matviienko suggested and it worked really well

In my case I worked with LinearLayout, in order to have more freedom to create the views

(I put it on my RecyclerView's onBindViewHolder to create a kind of custom ExpandableListView)

Follow snipped

Java

```
holder.header.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int newVisibility = holder.content.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE;
        holder.content.setVisibility(newVisibility);
    }
});
```

Layout xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Header" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Content" />

</LinearLayout>
```